# Is there any way to update a field of the records before the one currently inserted with a trigger?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Actually, I have been trying to update the field 'state' of my table 'TYPE_CHANGE' THROUGH A TRIGGER, but I have not been successful. I do not understand why I miss an error that says 'incorrect syntax' if what I extract is a datetime and I compare it with a datetime. I need help please. Thank you very much in advance.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TG_UPD_TIPO_CAMBIO ON TIPO_CAMBIO
AFTER INSERT
AS
    BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON;  
        DECLARE @VNIDMONEDA INT
        DECLARE @VDFECHATIPOCAMBIO DATETIME

        SELECT @VNIDMONEDA = NIDMONEDA, @VDFECHATIPOCAMBIO = DFECHATIPOCAMBIO FROM inserted  

        UPDATE TIPO_CAMBIO
        SET
            TIPO_CAMBIO.NESTADO = 0
        WHERE
            TIPO_CAMBIO.NIDMONEDA = @VNIDMONEDA AND 
            TIPO_CAMBIO.DFECHATIPOCAMBIO < @VDFECHATIPOCAMBIO
```

The error is : **"Mens 102, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Procedimiento TG_UPD_TIPO_CAMBIO, Línea 41
Incorrect syntax near '@VDFECHATIPOCAMBIO'."**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Nx0A.png)

Comment: Eventually you will find out that your approach is flawed. Until then, try posting the complete script you use to create the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

inserted may contains more than one row. What you are doing does not handle that

```
    UPDATE t
    SET
           TIPO_CAMBIO.NESTADO = 0
    FROM   
           INSERTED i
           INNER JOIN TIPO_CAMBIO t
           ON  t.TIPO_CAMBIO.NIDMONEDA        = i.VNIDMONEDA 
    WHERE 
           t.TIPO_CAMBIO.DFECHATIPOCAMBIO < i.VDFECHATIPOCAMBIO
```